# Sound in raw from EditText Data Storage

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech

Excuse me, can you help me. I'm making an application for children learning. The application of writing the alphabet in the form of "EditText". I want this text into sound from /raw. I have A.mp3 - Z.mp3 from /raw

```
MediaPlayer mplayer;
Button play;

private final View.OnClickListener playButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // play
        if (mplayer != null) {
            mplayer.start();

        }
    }
    };


     .........
       .........
       .........


    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    play.setOnClickListener(playButtonListener);
    mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.(txtToDisplay)); <------- this is error

       }
         .........
          .........
         .........
    //prediction.name is data storage
       txtToDisplay = prediction.name;
        showText1.setText(txtToDisplay);
```

My data storage is "prediction.name" or txtToDisplay. Prediction.name is A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H ... ,Z. My sound in /raw A.mp3, B.mp3. C.mp3 ... ,Z.mp3

This is full my java

```
package com.example.belajargesture;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.gesture.GestureLibraries;
import android.gesture.GestureLibrary;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView;
import android.gesture.Prediction;
import android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private GestureLibrary mLibrary;
    EditText showText1;
    String txtToDisplay = "";
    //musik
    MediaPlayer mplayer;
    Button play;
    //musik

    //musik
    private final View.OnClickListener playButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // play
            if (mplayer != null) {
                mplayer.start();

            }
        }
    };
    //musik


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!mLibrary.load()) {
            finish();
        }

        GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

        //musik
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        play.setOnClickListener(playButtonListener);
        mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
        //musik

    }

    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        showText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        // We want at least one prediction
        if (predictions.size() > 0) {
            Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
            // We want at least some confidence in the result
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                // Show the spell
                txtToDisplay = prediction.name;
                showText1.setText(txtToDisplay);

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I suppose txtToDisplay is your EditText? First, it needs a `txtToDisplay.getText()`. I also think you will need to append ".mp3". so `.....R.raw.(txtToDisplay.getText() + ".mp3")); `

Comment: I've tried it before but still error